# hide/display filter for tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, tablesorter

I d like to be able to hide/display the filters while using tablesorter.

Using table sorter just went fine but when i added a button to execute :

```
function display_hide_filter() {

    var filters = document.getElementsByClassName('tablesorter-filter-row');

     for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        var filter = filters[i];
        if (filter.style.display == 'none') {
            filter.style.display='inline';
        } else {
            filter.style.display='none';
        }
    }
}
```

I then get a weird answer. Hiding the filter is fine but re displaying turn into having all filter cells under the first header cell.

Since i got poor english and css/js skills, I just hope I didnt miss something about it in the documentation but i tried to get trough it a thousant times with no success.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Check the actual `display` value of the filter row before hiding it. It won't be `inline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`filter_hideFilters` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-hidefilters) that minimizes the filter row until the user hovers over it. It is also accessible friendly in that the user can use the tab key gain access the filter inputs ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/549/)).

If you just want to hide/show the filter row, then this basic code would work ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/548/)):

HTML

```
<button type="button">Toggle Filter Row</button>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
    });

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.tablesorter-filter-row').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mottie, this was exactly the demo I was looking for. I went through everything i could find but didnt see this one... Thanks a lot for your answer and your amazing work on this all :)

Answer (score 0):

As Andreas pointed out, I used 'inline' where i should have used ''